# Oracle equivalent for MySQL code "insert into dummy" to return error message

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a couple of hundred triggers in mysql db which i'm migrating to Oracle db. There's an statement that i see a lot which i haven't been able to find an equivalent one in oracle.

```
INSERT INTO $some_kind_of_message._BD_TRIGG$ (dummy) VALUES (value);
```

i've seen this also in procedures and functions, and it seems to 'return' a message to the aplication who calls the procedure (i think). i'm kind of new in both RDBMS but i've been working with oracle a couple of months.

Is there an equivalent statement to replace the mysql's one in oracle ? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

This is an example trigger of many. This one is used for login validation. 
I'm not very sure about oracle's trigger syntax but that's not the problem now.
The 'case' part is still in mysql syntax. I havent been able to find information in mysql nor oracle documentation. It is not a normal insert, it is some kind of *return message* that mysql uses (thats what i guess) and i've seen it also in functions and procedures.
¿How can i replace it for oracle to perform the same task?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER adduser 
BEFORE INSERT
ON tbl_users
FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE flag INTEGER;

  begin
  flag := 1;

  /* validate login */
  IF(LENGTH(TRIM(:NEW.login)) < 4) THEN
    flag := -1;
  END IF;

  /* valido clave */
  IF(flag = 1) THEN
    IF(LENGTH(:NEW.clave) < 3) THEN
      flag := -2;
    END IF;
  END IF;
    CASE flag
        WHEN -1 THEN INSERT INTO $login_less_then_4_characters._BD_TRIGG$ (dummy) VALUES ('error');
        WHEN -2 THEN INSERT INTO $pass_less_then_5_characters._BD_TRIGG$ (dummy) VALUES ('error');
        ELSE flag := 0;
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: I don't believe that an oracle trigger can return a value.  If it throws an exception that will be returned. You could always do an insert into another table from inside the trigger, if you wanted to create transaction tables or something of that nature.

Comment: Oracle has proper exception handling. It's not necessary to generate an error in order "send" a message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR()` function/procedure.

Syntax:

```
raise_application_error(error code, your error message);
```

Example:

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Login must have 4 characters or more');
```

In Oracle custom aplication error codes are between `-20000` and `-20999`.

More information here:

[Oracle PL/SQL - Raise User-Defined Exception With Custom SQLERRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020450/oracle-pl-sql-raise-user-defined-exception-with-custom-sqlerrm)

Oracle documentation: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329)

Comment: I will take a look at the examples.

Comment: @AlejandroBastidas I added some info. Im not an Oracle expert,  but that one line should work without any declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MySQL syntax but in Oracle it translates as

```
Insert into table_name(column_name) VALUES (value);
```

where dummy is a column in some table or parameter passed to function. You cannot use procedures, triggers in Insert statements in Oracle. You may use Function() in DML statements, e.g. SELECT your_function(dummy)..., INSERT your_function(dummy)... And function returns a value as we all know.