# Oracle SQL Trigger insert new records based on a insert column value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a trigger for a Oracle table. Here are the requirements
I have two tables Books, Copies (Books & copies have a 1 to n relationship. Each book can have 0 to n copies)

Book Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
  (
    book_id      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    isbn         VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
    publisher_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    tittle       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL ,
    cat_id       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    no_of_copies INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    ....
    CONSTRAINT isbn_unique UNIQUE (isbn),
    CONSTRAINT shelf_letter_unique UNIQUE (shelf_letter, call_number) 
  ) ;
```

Copies Table

```
CREATE TABLE Copies
  (
    copy_id     INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    book_id     INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    copy_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    constraint copy_number_unique unique(book_id,copy_number)
  ) ;
```

The trigger (on update,edit of a the Book table) should add its corresponding copy records into Copies table. So if a insert into Books table has  Book.no_of_copies as 5 then five new records should be inserted into the Copies table..

Comment: What? And how should we decide `copy_id`? And if `no_of_copies` is edited e.g. from 5 to 3, which rows of copies should be deleted?

Comment: copy_id is the primary key and is on Auto Increment. Regarding 5 to 3 reduction, the requirement says that it should throw an application error (so basically it's not allowed). But if it's increased from 5 to 7, two more records should be added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda long, but actually quite straightforward.

Tested on a Oracle 10gR2 setup.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE books
(
  book_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  no_of_copies INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_book_id PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE copies
(
  book_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  copy_no INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_books_add
  AFTER INSERT ON books
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  num INTEGER:=1;
BEGIN
  IF :new.no_of_copies>0 THEN
    WHILE num<=:new.no_of_copies LOOP
      INSERT INTO copies (book_id,copy_no) VALUES (:new.book_id,num);
      num:=num+1;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TRIGGER tri_books_edit
  BEFORE UPDATE ON books
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  num INTEGER:=1;
BEGIN
  IF :new.no_of_copies<:old.no_of_copies THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Decrease of copy number prohibited.');
  ELSIF :new.no_of_copies>:old.no_of_copies THEN
    SELECT max(copy_no)+1 INTO num FROM copies WHERE book_id=:old.book_id;
    WHILE num<=:new.no_of_copies LOOP
      INSERT INTO copies (book_id,copy_no) VALUES (:old.book_id,num);
      num:=num+1;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

What the trigger do:

- For the `tri_books_add`

  1. use a `num` to "remember" `copy_no`;
  2. use a [`WHILE-LOOP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#CJACCEAC) statement to add copies.
- For the `tri_books_edit`

  1. use a `num` to "remember" `copy_no`;
  2. [check if](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#CJAJGBEE) new `no_of_copies` is illegally decreased; if so, [raise a custom error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6020450);
  3. append copies.

The reason I separate books inserting and editing into two triggers, is because I employed a [`foreign key` constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#i1002118), so `after insert` would be needed for inserting (correct me if I'm wrong on this, though).

I then run some test:

```
INSERT INTO books (book_id,no_of_copies) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO books (book_id,no_of_copies) VALUES (2,5);
```

```
SQL> select * from copies;

   BOOK_ID    COPY_NO
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         2          1
         2          2
         2          3
         2          4
         2          5

8 rows selected.

SQL> update books set no_of_copies=5 where book_id=1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from copies;

   BOOK_ID    COPY_NO
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         2          1
         2          2
         2          3
         2          4
         2          5
         1          4
         1          5

10 rows selected.

SQL> update books set no_of_copies=3 where book_id=1;
update books set no_of_copies=3 where book_id=1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Decrease of copy number prohibited.
ORA-06512: at "LINEQZ.TRI_BOOKS_EDIT", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LINEQZ.TRI_BOOKS_EDIT'
```

(I don't seem to be able to make [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to work on triggers so no online demos, sorry.)

Comment: Awesome. Can appreciate you enough for this detailed answer. Thanks for your hard work! I'm now even more motivated to learn Oracle programming.

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for INSERT and UPDATE in table BOOK. It would insert rows in COPIES table only when either a new row is inserted in table BOOK, or an existing row in table BOOK is updated with no_of_copies greater than its current value.

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
book_id      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
isbn         VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
publisher_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
tittle       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL ,
cat_id       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
no_of_copies INTEGER NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT isbn_unique UNIQUE (isbn) 
) ;

CREATE TABLE Copies
(
copy_id     INTEGER NOT NULL ,
book_id     INTEGER NOT NULL ,
copy_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
constraint copy_number_unique unique(book_id,copy_number)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE COPY_SEQ
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE;
```

---

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BOOK
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_CURR_COPIES    NUMBER;
V_COUNT          NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

 IF  :NEW.NO_OF_COPIES > NVL(:OLD.NO_OF_COPIES, 0) THEN
     SELECT COUNT(1)
     INTO   V_CURR_COPIES   --# of rows in COPIES table for a particular book.
     FROM   COPIES C
     WHERE  C.BOOK_ID = :NEW.BOOK_ID;

     WHILE  V_COUNT < :NEW.NO_OF_COPIES - V_CURR_COPIES
     LOOP
         INSERT INTO COPIES
         (
         COPY_ID,
         BOOK_ID,
         COPY_NUMBER
         )
         SELECT COPY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                :NEW.BOOK_ID,
                V_COUNT + V_CURR_COPIES + 1
         FROM   DUAL;

         V_COUNT := V_COUNT + 1;
     END LOOP;
 END IF;
END;
```

---

Testing:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK
VALUES (1, 'ABCDEF', 2, 'TEST BOOK', 1, 3);

UPDATE BOOK B
SET    B.NO_OF_COPIES = 4
WHERE  B.BOOK_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace 
trigger BOOK_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON BOOK 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE L_COPIES NUMBER:= :NEW.NO_OF_COPIES;
BEGIN
     FOR I IN 1..5
     LOOP
          INSERT
          INTO COPIES
               (
                    COPY_ID,
                    BOOK_ID,
                    COPY_NUMBER
               )
               VALUES
               (
                    1, -- your copy sequence
                    :new.book_id,
                    i
               );
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. Much apreciated!