# Can we raise an exception within an exception?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can we raise an exception within an exception, like `RAISE my_exception` within an `WHEN OTHERS` exception?

Additionally, I am trying to understand the output in the following 2 scenarios:
*(Note that the only difference is the ordering of the exceptions)*

**Scenario 1**

```
DECLARE
     lc_exception Exception;
     var1 number;
BEGIN
     select 1
     into var1
     from dual
     where 1=2;
EXCEPTION
     when lc_exception then
       dbms_output.put_line('This is my exception');

     when no_data_found then
       raise lc_exception;

     when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('There could be some other exception');
END;
```

**Scenario 2**

```
DECLARE
     lc_exception Exception;
     var1 number;
BEGIN
     select 1
     into var1
     from dual
     where 1=2;
EXCEPTION
     when no_data_found then
       raise lc_exception; 

     when lc_exception then
       dbms_output.put_line('This is my exception');

     when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('There could be some other exception');
END;
```

Comment: Yes, you can raise another exception in an exception handler.

Comment: Could you please also answer for the above 2 scenarios

Comment: [Give this thread a try first.... :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020450/oracle-pl-sql-raise-user-defined-exception-with-custom-sqlerrm)

Comment: @NoobEditor --> I have gone through the above mentioned thread before putting up my question. I believe my question is bit different (if you go through scenarios) from the above mentioned thread.                           Anyways thanks a lot for your help.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Both scenarios have the similar error stack:

```
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at line 20
ORA-01403: no data found
```

The only difference is the exact location (line 20 vs. 18) where the user defined exception is raised.

1. The select matches no rows thus `no_data_found` is raised by Oracle - `ORA-01403: no data found` in the error stack.
2. The exception is caught by the block's exception handler block.
3. In the exception handler an user defined exception `lc_exception` is raised.
4. Because the program has no other exception handlers the user defined exception is leaked to host environment (in my case that was sqlplus client) - `ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception` and program terminates.

The exception propagation is similar in both scenarios because in both cases the same initial exception `no_data_found` is raised and there is only one exception handling block. Therefore the order of `no_data_found` and `lc_exception` handlers doesn't matter.

More detailed explanation about exception handling/propagation is found from: [PL/SQL Error Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#LNPLS00701) in Oracle documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot user272735

Answer (score 1):

You just need an exception handler to catch your local exception. If you raise an exception in an exception handler, it cannot be caught in the same exception hander.

```
DECLARE
  lc_exception EXCEPTION;
  var1 number;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO var1
    FROM dual
    WHERE 1=2;
  EXCEPTION -- this is where the exception will be raised
    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
      raise lc_exception;
  END;

  dbms_output.put_line( 'This will never be executed.' );

EXCEPTION -- this is where the exception will be caught
  WHEN lc_exception THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'This is my exception' );

  WHEN others THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'There could be some other exception' );
END;
```

However, you may want to consider a slightly different method.

```
DECLARE
  lc_exception EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( lc_exception, -20222 );
  var1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO var1
    FROM dual
    WHERE 1=2;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20222, 'This is my exception' );
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'This will never be executed.' );

EXCEPTION
    WHEN lc_exception THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Some other exception: ' || SQLERRM );
END;
```