# how to provide error message when rising oracle predefined exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I rise DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX in SQL and I'd like to associate some custom error message with it.
Right now after executing the code

```
IF ___SOME_CONDITION___ THEN
  RAISE DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
END IF
```

I see following message:

```
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
```

How I can provide custom message to substitute these "%s"?

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't typically raise these pre-defined errors yourself. Instead, you would either let the database raise them (eg. you really have tried to insert a row that violates the unique constraint/index) or raise your own custom error (eg. `raise_application_error()`) and provide the necessary information there.

Comment: Oracle documentation says you may use these predefined exceptions and has an example. I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: @Sergey This a valid answer - _"you wouldn't typically raise these pre-defined errors yourself"_. Instead define and raise your own `unique_constraint_violated` exception (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6020450). (I'm not aware of any ways how to substitute the placeholders in the predefined exception texts.)

Comment: @Sergey It's entirely possible to go jump off a cliff. That doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea to do so! Yes, you can certainly raise the predefined errors as much as you like, but you have to bear in mind that Oracle has not provided a way for you to pass parameters into them.

Comment: @Boneist _Oracle has not provided a way for you to pass parameters into them_. Thank you, this is what I've looked for.