# PLSQL EXCEPTION not working

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I am trying to raise an exception when the procedure does not insert a record. My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
    p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
    p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
    p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
    p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
    p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
    p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)
IS
    -- Variables    
    x number:=0;
    y number:=0;  
    CLASS_CLASH EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    -- checks
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 
                FROM TUTPRAC
                 WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc and CLASS_DAY = p_classd 
                  or CLASS_DAY = p_classd and CLASS_TIME = p_classt
                  and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) , 0) 
    INTO x FROM dual;
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 
                FROM UNITSTREAM 
                WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc and DAY = p_classd 
                or DAY = p_classd and TIME = p_classt 
                and LOCATION = p_roomnm) , 0) 
    INTO y FROM dual;
    -- insert
    IF (x = 0 and y = 0) THEN
      INSERT INTO TUTPRAC (CLASSID, UNITCODE, CLASS_DAY, CLASS_TIME, CLASS_TYPE, ROOMNUM) 
      VALUES (p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm);
    ELSE
      RAISE CLASS_CLASH;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN CLASS_CLASH THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record was not inserted due to a class clash.');
END OPEN_CLASS;
```

When I run this procedure, if the record does not have any clashes it says `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.` and it adds a record into the table. The problem is that even if it finds a clash and *doesn't* add a record it still says that same message instead of the output from my exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6020450/2091410 - see the first answer, which should help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you catch your exception within your procedure - the procedure does not terminate abnormally. So, `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.` is the correct output.  To make your procedure throw an exception you need to issue a `raise;` in the EXCEPTION block.

If you don't see the message this might be because of `DBMS_OUTPUT` output being suppressed. Check if you see any output if you put `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` as the first line of your procedure. If you don't - check that you're calling `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` in your sqlplus session before calling your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have executed `set serveroutput on` in your session.

Your code will throw exception no data found. I think you're expecting a `NULL` when there is no match so you've used NVL. But the select statements will not return anything instead of the `NULL` you're expecting.

It is the reason for no data found exception.

You can use `count(*) into x` and `count(*) into y` instead of the NVLs. It should work as expected.