# Oracle: Capturing Specific Oracle Message with EXCEPTION_INIT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, exception

I want to handle an exception for `ORA-000942` and am following this [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i9355) and this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020450/oracle-pl-sql-raise-user-defined-exception-with-custom-sqlerrm). Since this is an `ORA-` error with no predefined name, I want to use `exception_init.`

When I run this code, I continue to get the `ORA-000942` message, but not as expected via the procedure level handler.

```
create table foobar (foobar_id varchar(1));

declare

 procedure p_add_to_foobar
 is
 p_missing_table exception;
 pragma exception_init(p_missing_table, -00942);

 begin
 insert into foobaz   
 select '1' from dual;

  exception
  when p_missing_table then
  dbms_output.put_line('MISSING TABLE'); 
  end p_add_to_foobar;  


 begin
 p_add_to_foobar;
 dbms_output.put_line('DONE');
 end;
```

**Question:**

1. How do I get my procedure level exception to handle the **-942** error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is being thrown by the PL/SQL compiler when it tries to compile the statement

```
insert into foobaz
  select 1 from dual
```

because of course the `foobaz` table doesn't exist. In-line SQL statements have to be valid at compile time, and thus the compiler throws an exception.

To get around this you'll have to use dynamic SQL, as in:

```
declare
 procedure p_add_to_foobar is
   p_missing_table exception;
   pragma exception_init(p_missing_table, -00942);
 begin
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'insert into foobaz   
       select ''1'' from dual';
  exception
    when p_missing_table then
      dbms_output.put_line('MISSING TABLE'); 
  end p_add_to_foobar;
BEGIN
  p_add_to_foobar;
  dbms_output.put_line('DONE');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WHEN OTHERS: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

The above produces the expected output:

```
MISSING TABLE
DONE
```

Best of luck.

Comment: yes, it fails on compilation, before you are able to execute it