# Raise_application_error in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, raise, application-error

I'm using SQL Developer Version 17.2.0.188. When I compile code, which cause some error, e.g. 
begin
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'xxxxx');
end;

I see the error message in script outputs(like dbms_output), but i would like to see it in a new window, similar when you declare some bind variable: 
     variable_name number := &value;
Could somebody tell me where in SQL Developer can I change the seetings to make this window visible?

I don't have option in this version of SQL developer:
Tools -> Preferences -> User Interface -> Options -> DSA Dialogs...

Best regards, Derk.

Comment: Have you searched it at all?

Comment: "but i would like to see it in a new window, similar when you declare some bind variable:" - you want a pop up dialog with the error text?

Comment: Exactly. It is going about pop up. Of course, I searched but i haven't find solution.

Comment: Unlikely i don't have the option "User Interface" in this version of sql developer.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: that question relates to Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer, this question relates to Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @LukeWoodward oh excuse me, i was confused.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - to be fair the OP contributed to the confusion by tagging the question `[plsqldeveloper]` rather than `[oracle-sqldeveloper]` (although Horseman has since edited the tags).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL Developer doesn't work this way. Error messages are written to the Script Output or Query Result panels, depending on if your code was executed via F5 or F9, respectively.

PL/SQL compiler warnings and errors are written to the Log - Compiler panel.

[image]

```
create or replace procedure xyz123 is
begin
 null
end;
/

show errors
```

Additionally, if you want to see DBMS_OUTPUT included, then SET SERVEROUTPUT ON. It will get written to the Script Output panel.

[image]

Now, about raising an exception, this still happens in a PL/SQL block, and we'd still execute that via F5 (Script Output.)

([Code borrowed from SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020523/1156452))

```
DECLARE
    ex_custom EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init ( ex_custom,-20001 );
BEGIN
    raise_application_error(
        -20001,
        'This is a custom error'
    );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_custom THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```

Execute with F5, and...

[image]

Comment: In my job I'm using SQL Developer Version 1.5.5 and the error pop up is visible.

Comment: 1.5.5 is about 12 years old... Time to upgrade

Comment: Do I understand properly that this features is impossible to achive in new version of SQL Developer? A liitle odd, because it is difficult to differ this message from dbms_output, especially when the error causes some trigger..

Comment: @Derk I just tried version 2.1 as well, from 2010. It operates the same as today. As for catching exceptions, it's a common best practice to log those to a table as explained here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-mar/o22plsql-1518275.html. If you're running this code in a script via SQL*Plus, SQLcl, SQL Developer, then writing to DBMS_OUTPUT is probably OK

Comment: thatjeffsmith 
It is going rather about situation, when I do same syntax mistake. Then I don't  want to ask me whether it is some trigger or my mistake..
"It operates the same as today." Could you tell me then what should i change in the settings to see the pop up after click on execute a script?
Best regards

Comment: if you have an error in your code or script, it will display in the panels as i've shown in the screenshots.

Comment: But it works in this way in Version 17.2.0.188. In 1.5.5 i see the pop up after click on the button. Look here: zapodaj.net/940fb94cc928c.png.html

Comment: @Derk yes, it worked that way in 1.5.5, but no more, and not for a long time -- see my note about logging your exceptions in TABLES. if you don't do this, you're going to miss problems whether you have popups or not

Comment: This method is familiar to me. I'm using Toad too and the pop up is genereted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Derk sorry, but at least you have your answer.