# Adding an exception (calling function) into procedure - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Having some problems with adding function calling exception in the procedure. I hope it's just some syntax misstake.
The exception unauthorised is checking if the correct owner of the account deposits money in to the account. To handle that I call function get_authorisation. The code works itself without the exception. Could someone check it? Thank you!

```
 create or replace procedure do_utt(
     p_radnr in utt.radnr%type,
     p_pnr in utt.pnr%type,
     p_knr in utt.knr%type,
     p_belopp in utt.belopp%type,
     p_datum in utt.datum%type)

     declare unauthorised exception;
     as
     begin
     insert into utt(radnr, pnr, knr, belopp, datum)
     values (radnr_seq.nextval, p_pnr, p_knr, 
             p_belopp, sysdate);

        if get_authorisation(p_knr) = 0 then
        raise unauthorised ;
        end if;

     commit;
     dbms_output.put_line('Balance '|| p_knr || ' is: 
                          '||get_saldo(p_knr));
     exception
     when unauthorised then
     dbms_output.put_line('You are not the owner of the account!');
  end;
  /
```

Errors: PROCEDURE DO_UTT
Line/Col: 8/2 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

; is with default authid as cluster order using external
deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache
accessible rewrite

The code for function:

```
  create or replace function get_authorisation (
    p_pnr in owner.pnr%type,
    p_knr in owner.knr%type)
    return number
    as
    v_authorised number;
    v_no_authorised exception;
    begin
    select count(*)      
    into v_authorised
    from owner
    where pnr = p_pnr 
    and knr = p_knr;
    return v_authorised;

    exception
    when v_no_authorised then
    return 0;
  end;
```

Comment: move "as" up before the delare.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your own excepcion with the PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT clause and then throw the exception with RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR as it's shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020523/518

Note: you should use an error code less than -20000 (in the answer -20001 is used)

Answer (score 0):

--I changed the code with PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT --

```
create or replace procedure do_utt(
p_radnr in utt.radnr%type,
p_pnr in utt.pnr%type,
p_knr in utt.knr%type,
p_belopp in utt.belopp%type,
p_datum in utt.datum%type)
as

declare 
unauthorised exception;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( unauthorised, -20001 );

begin
insert into utt(radnr, pnr, knr, belopp, datum)
values (radnr_seq.nextval, p_pnr, p_knr, p_belopp, sysdate);
commit;
dbms_output.put_line('Balance '|| p_knr || ' is: '||get_saldo(p_knr));
raise_application_error (20001, 'You are not the account owner!');
exception
when get_authorisation = 0 then
dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
end;
```

**Errors: PROCEDURE DO_UTTAG
Line/Col: 8/2 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:**

**begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
 current cursor delete
exists prior external language
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.
Line/Col: 19/26 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
. then or**